# Short on ideas: new web app suggestion

Tags: web-applications

You know, sometimes it happens that you run out of ideas for your next hobbistic programming project, and then... you ask for help on StackOverflow :)

So: what would it be your suggestion for a rocking web application (it may be implemented using [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) and it may use the new fresh [Google Friend Connect](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/) APIs) to develop in 20 or 30 days of spare time?

Any constructive and creative suggestion is warmly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Why not join an existing Open Source project using those technologies? In my opinion it is a great way to learn new stuff and picking up good habits :-)

Answer (score 2):

My current open source itches are:

- iwantsandy alternative - personal assistant bot over twitter, SMS and email.
- make my music collection available via https. Must include play lists. Must synch with iTunes, or anything else I choose.

Does it have to be a web project?

Learning more new languages:

- Scala - top of the list
- Python

Learn more theory:

- Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs videos.

Answer (score 1):

An application tracking allergies (symptoms, counter indicators, food lists and places where you can actually buy such food).

The tricky part would be to allow users to filter the data without exposing their own health to the world. I was thinking about a client side CSS file which hides the part of the site which is not relevant plus a strict policy not to track page access and/or IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

An **auto page-refresher for StackOverflow** :)

..will be quite useful when watching for new entries and such